# rtsp for sony-max in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp

i have an android app that will live stream videos in android 2.3.3,i have found on that rtsp link in videoview works for that purpose from

```
String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

.But i am not getting any rtsp working link for sony max or sony six.
i have tried 
rtsp://208.77.20.52:1935/dmm1/setmax.
any 1 having any idea about what can be done??
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are you playing the video? flash players are not supported in many android devices

Comment: yes i am facing that issue when i use webview and play flashvideoo.but in videoview that is working fine.